# How can I get an entity with linq-query that is not in context?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, crm

my plugin triggers on "Create" -xxx-Entity. in ServiceContextI have notes that belong only to this entity. But for example, I want all the notes in CRM or all the records belonging to another entity that are not in ServiceContext. How can I retrieve it?

```
var ServiceContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

 var notes = from n in ServiceContext.CreateQuery("annotation")
 where n["objectid"] == new EntityReference("xxx", xxx.Id)
                            select n;
```

Comment: Please provide some more context, as to what you're trying to do. I couldn't quite understand it.

However, one thing I noticed, is your check will always fail. You're creating a new object and checking if an existing object is equal to it. 
I'd suggest using the [Object.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2) method for these kinds of checks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
this code works fine. So it's not about "Equal" or "==" but about objects that exist in ServiceContext. The problem is, once the plugin is triggered, I can only retrieve the objects that are in ServiceContext. But I want actually to get all the notes (objects) in crm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OrganizationServiceContext can query any entity without limits. You can use the same query, just remove the where clause and you'll get all notes:

```
var query = from n in ServiceContext.CreateQuery("annotation")
            select n;
var allNotes = query.ToList();
```

Or, for notes related to another record:

```
var query = from n in ServiceContext.CreateQuery("annotation")
where n.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("objectid").Id.Equals(myObjectId)
select n;
```

For notes that have attachments, unless you need the `documentbody`, leaving that out of the query can speed things up.

Comment: Thank you very much,
Because I'm a beginner, I have a question, what do you prefer for query in CRM: Fetch xml, linq, or QueryExpression?

Comment: Glad to help. If you know LINQ, that's generally the easiest way to query data quickly. Outside of LINQ I typically go to FetchXML for things like aggregates. Query Expression is nice too, but can get a bit verbose for complex queries.

Comment: Just to build on @Aron comment, if you choose to use FetchXML then you can also use the Advanced Find in CRM to help get you started. You just build your query in the UI and use the "Download Fetch XML" button.